# Python C API: How to check if an object is an instance of a type

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I want to check if an object is an instance of a certain class. In Python I can do this with `isinstance(obj, cls)`. In C/C++, I found a function named [PyObject_IsInstance](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsInstance). But it seems not to work like `isinstance`.

In detail (also described as sample codes below):

1. In C++ I defined my custom type `My`. The type definition is `MyType` and the object definition is `MyObject`.
2. Add `MyType` to the exported module with name `My`.
3. In Python, create a new instance `my = My()`, and `isinstance(my, My)` returns `True`.
4. While in C++ we use `PyObject_IsInstance(my, (PyObject*)&MyType)` to check `my`, and this returns `0`, which means `my` is not an instance of the class defined by `MyType`.

Full C++ code:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <python3.6/Python.h>
#include <python3.6/structmember.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    int num;
} MyObject;

static PyTypeObject MyType = []{
    PyTypeObject ret = {
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    };
    ret.tp_name = "cpp.My";
    ret.tp_doc = NULL;
    ret.tp_basicsize = sizeof(MyObject);
    ret.tp_itemsize = 0;
    ret.tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT;
    ret.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
    return ret;
}();

// check if obj is an instance of MyType
static PyObject *Py_fn_checkMy(PyObject *obj) {
    if (PyObject_IsInstance(obj, (PyObject *)&MyType)) Py_RETURN_TRUE;
    else Py_RETURN_FALSE;
}

static PyMethodDef modmethodsdef[] = {
    { "checkMy", (PyCFunction)Py_fn_checkMy, METH_VARARGS, NULL },
    { NULL }
};

static PyModuleDef moddef = []{
    PyModuleDef ret = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT
    };
    ret.m_name = "cpp";
    ret.m_doc = NULL;
    ret.m_size = -1;
    return ret;
}();

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_cpp(void)
{
    PyObject *mod;
    if (PyType_Ready(&MyType) < 0)
        return NULL;
    mod = PyModule_Create(&moddef);
    if (mod == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(&MyType);
    PyModule_AddObject(mod, "My", (PyObject *)&MyType);
    PyModule_AddFunctions(mod, modmethodsdef);
    return mod;
}
```

Compile this into `cpp.so`, and test it in Python:

```
>>> import cpp
>>> isinstance(cpp.My(), cpp.My)
True
>>> cpp.checkMy(cpp.My())
False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`METH_VARARGS`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#METH_VARARGS)

> This is the typical calling convention, where the methods have the type PyCFunction. The function expects two `PyObject*` values. The first one is the self object for methods; for module functions, it is the module object. The second parameter (often called args) is a tuple object representing all arguments. This parameter is typically processed using `PyArg_ParseTuple()` or `PyArg_UnpackTuple()`.

The function signature of `Py_fn_checkMy` does not match this. It should take two arguments. The first is the module, and this is what you are checking against `MyType`. The second argument (which you don't actually accept) is a tuple containing the object you passed. You should extract the argument from the tuple and check the type of this.

You'd probably be better using `METH_O` to specify a single argument instead of extracting arguments from a tuple:

```
static PyObject *Py_fn_checkMy(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj) {
    if (PyObject_IsInstance(obj, (PyObject *)&MyType)) Py_RETURN_TRUE;
    else Py_RETURN_FALSE;
}


static PyMethodDef modmethodsdef[] = {
    { "checkMy", (PyCFunction)Py_fn_checkMy, METH_O, NULL },
    { NULL }
};
```